# DynamicsCRM SQL Query - rsbexpr#### is not a unique alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, dynamics-crm, aggregate-functions

I am using a CData JDBC Driver to talk to DynamicsCRM Online. I was testing some queries with aggregate functions and in the Lead table there are 2 fields that don't work together.

If I run the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUM(Lead.Address1_UTCOffset), SUM(Lead.BudgetAmount_Base) FROM Lead
```

I get the error: `rsbexpr2045 is not a unique alias`

This happens if I switch SUM to any other aggregate function, but in the error the number after 'rsbexpr' changes. The values of that number for some aggregates are as follows:

- `SUM` - 2045
- `AVG` - 2022
- `MIN` - 2028
- `MAX` - 2030
- `COUNT` - 2193

I haven't tested to see if the same applies to other tables but wanted to know if there was anyone else who ran into this problem.

**EDIT 1**

Another example I have come across, the query:

`SELECT AVG(Invoice.DiscountAmount_Base), MAX(Invoice.TotalLineItemAmount) FROM Invoice`

Returns the error:

`rsbexpr2260 is not a unique alias`

**EDIT 2**

I tried all of the different combinations of the aggregate types I know of and for the last example (Edit 1) it works fine with all of them except having AVG on the first and MAX on the second.

Comment: I don't know anything about JDBC, but it could be that you need to specify column names. Currently you're getting 2 columns with the same name.

Try
SELECT TOP 10 SUM(Lead.Address1_UTCOffset) as a, SUM(Lead.BudgetAmount_Base) as b FROM Lead

Answer (score 0):

You need to add explicit aliases to your query, for example

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  SUM(Lead.Address1_UTCOffset) as utcoffset_sum,
  SUM(Lead.BudgetAmount_Base) as budgetamount_sum 
FROM Lead
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still gives the same error. Originally I had a lot more fields in the query, all with Aliases, I isolated the problem to those 2 fileds and removed the Aliases to simplify the question.